# How to remove already installed laminate panel in cabinet?

Tags: cabinets, laminate, saw

This is actually a kitchen cabinet. The company I ordered it from messed up, so the oven I am installing inside the opening won't fit.

However, if I **remove the TOP and BOTTOM panels (highlighted yellow)** from the opening, the oven will fit!

My problem is the cabinet installation is already done, meaning, unlike my drawing below, I don't have access to the dowel tensioners and can't disassemble it without too much work involved; it's actually a middle cabinet with other cabinets beside it, so I have to disassemble the ENTIRE kitchen cabinetry in order to remove just those 2 panels.

The panels are attached to the sides with wood dowels and metal dowels with tensioners. Standard/typical stuff.

**What I plan to do is HAND SAW the panels in the middle (dotted line), then pull them off, destroying them from the dowel joints.**

I just don't know how to do it properly. I have a circular saw. I can probably adjust the cut depth to match the panel's thickness. However, it is too risky (to damage the panel below it), and I obviously can't use the circular saw for the top panel (not foolish enough to use a circular saw upside down).

I do have a 26" fine teeth (12 tpi) hand saw. I am planning to just use that.

Any other ideas that may be more efficient? I have a jigsaw, recip saw, and circular saw.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if the  panel is particle board beneath the laminate?

Comment: Yes, it's particle board under the laminate

Answer (score 1):

Cut through particle board panels as far as you can with jig saw. Most likely they are not attached in the back.  The remaining 1-2 inches of the panel may be easy to break apart. If not finish cutting through with small hand saw. When 2 halves are separated pry each straight back from side panel to disengage the dowels .
On the top panel if you don't have space to run jig saw flip the saw over and cut through from bottom of shelf panel.